# Howto restore Windows bootloader after removing Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, windows-7

I have installed ubuntu 14.04 and windows 7 with dual boot.Now the problem is my ubuntu was crash so i delete the ubuntu partition in windows diskmanagement but the default boot priority is ubuntu now i can not open my windows operating system. Is there any way to change the boot priority? if so how to do that?

Comment: I'd say the boot priority is of very little concern, when you can't boot either OS. You should [restore the Windows bootloader](https://www.google.co.il/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=restore+Windows+7+bootloader&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=67mRU5mNMoqb_wal1YDIAw&gbv=1&sei=7LmRU8v6EszP4QTsloG4DQ), instead of worrying which boots first.

Comment: Wow.. that seems a really windows try [this](https://kb.acronis.com/content/1507)

Answer (score 0):

=> u need a windows 7 repair disc or windows 7 live usb or cd

boot from any of the above windows disc and go to 'repair using windows command prompt'

type the following two commands in cmd

Bootrec/fixmbr 'press enter'

Bootrec/fixboot 'press enter'

now reboot u can see windows boot loader again

Answer (score 0):

Be carefull to mess with mbr as it can leads to Blue screen of death (BSOD). So it is best to reinstall windows. Bootrec/fixmbr command will be executed successfully and you will be able to reboot if error is not complex.